# Why isn't this code in ViewDidLoad executing?

Tags: swift

I have two text fields, one button, and four labels.

When you push the button, it should update the four labels.
Label 1: name
Label 2: email
Label 3: name (same data as label 1)
Label 4: email (same data as label 2)

I was experimenting under `viewDidLoad()` to see if I can make another var and update my last label.  No error when I run the code, but it turns out "empty" in the simulator.

Can anyone explain why?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var emailInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!


    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: Any) {
        var text = nameInput.text
        var email = emailInput.text


        label.text = text
        label2.text = email

        label3.text = text
    }

//where i experimented:

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var email2 = emailInput.text
        label4.text = email2



}


}
```

Comment: In viewDidLoad, the user has not put any text into the text fields yet. So no big surprise.

Comment: Because emailInput textfield don't have any text. In storyboard add some text in emailInput to get text in viewdidload or move this code to actionButton

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
label4.text = email2
```

To

```
label4.text = "howdy"
```

Now you will see something in your interface.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewDidLoad` method called in the beginning perfectly. But the label not showing any data because initially the textfield has no value. That's the label not contains any data.

Please set any value to the label initially. Like

```
label4.text = "Something"
```

Hope you can understand that the viewDidLoad is called perfectly.